# deposit payment with different percentage for different product

Tags: woocommerce, payment

I need something like a deposit payment:

service total cost is 100 euros
20 euros you pay now to me with realex
with the remaining 80 euros customer will pay later to my partners via bank transfer
for every service I have to set different percentage to deposit.

Maybe its explained better in picture below:

https://imageshack.com/f/eyGK6UcQp

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Did you try Google? "WooCommerce Deposits" yields at least 4 plugins that handle deposits.

Comment: I have found some differents plug-in but in none of these, I can set a different deposit value for each product.

Comment: Then you probably need to hire someone to build something custom or to at least extend one of the existing solutions.

Answer (score -1):

Not to promote myself or anything, but here's my new WooCommerce plugin, which does exactly this:

http://codecanyon.net/item/woocommerce-deposits-partial-payments-plugin/9249233?ref=voodooattack